# PHP OOP include_path error

Tags: php, apache, oop, include

> Warning: require(_header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\pages\index.php on line 1
>   Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '_header.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\htdocs\classes;C:\xampp\htdocs\pages;C:\xampp\htdocs\mod;C:\xampp\htdocs\inc;;.C:\xampp\php\pear\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\pages\index.php on line 1

I got this error?

Any one can tell how can I fix this?

Comment: Show us your code where you include your file `_header.php` and show your folder structure, where `index.php` is located and where `_header.php` is located

Comment: <?php require_once('_header.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('_footer.php'); ?>

Comment: <?php
index.php 
require_once('inc/autoload.php');

$core = new Core();
$core->run();
?>

Comment: Please use the [**edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30623380/edit) Button of your question to add stuff to your question.

Comment: Actually I need to know how set path to this folder in php.in file.(xampp server)